# How to get enum member index (not member name) in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following enum:

```
export enum Categoria {
    Acao = 1,
    Opcao = 2,
    FundoImobiliario = 3,
    ContratoFuturo = 4,
    ETF = 5,
    BDR = 6
}
```

I use the following code to return the enum members to the screen:

```
export function enumSelector(objeto: any) {
    return Object.keys(objeto).filter(key => !isNaN(Number(objeto[key])));
}
```

This enum populates an HTML select. So I select an option and do the post on my form, but what I get is the member name enum. How do I get the enum index? For example: 1 or 2 or 3 etc.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  If you want a mapping from key to value of the enum, you could use the enum directly, possibly without the built-in reverse mapping, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5q6W).  But if that's all you want, you probably shouldn't use an `enum` anyway.  What's wrong with just [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4pjXW) using a `const` instead of an `enum`?

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you with the issue you are handling (keyof)

```
enum socialMedia {
Instagram = 1,
Facebook,
Whatsapp,
Snapchat
}
type KeyofEnum = keyof socialMedia;
function getsocialMedia(mediaOfficial: string): socialMedia {
if (mediaOfficial === 'Filters' || mediaOfficial === 'Snaps') {
return socialMedia.Snapchat;
}
}
let mediaType: socialMedia = getsocialMedia('Snaps'); // returns Snapchat
console.log('keyof enum string type Snapchat is', mediaType);
```

Output:

```
TypeScript keyof Enum 1
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question as asked.  And `keyof socialMedia` is equivalent to `"toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"`, which is unlikely to be anything anyone wants.  Could you elaborate about what you are doing and how it is intended to apply as an answer?